# Limit of $x_{n+1}=\int _0^1\min\left\{x,x_n\right\}\,\mathrm dx$ with $x_1=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**Question:**

> If $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\int _0^1\min\left\{x,x_n\right\}\,\mathrm dx$ , how to prove $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x_n\right)$ exits?

========update======

My progress is:

$x_{n+1}=\int _0^{x_n}\min\left\{x,x_n\right\}dx+\int _{x_n}^1\min\left\{x,x_n\right\}dx=\int _0^{x_n}xdx+\int _{x_n}^1x_ndx=\frac{x_n^2}{2}+x_{n\left(1-x_n\right)}\:=x_n-\frac{x_n^2}{2}$

**But I don't know how to prove** $0<x_{n+1}<x_n$.Can you give me a detailed explanation?

Comment: $\frac{x_n^2}{2} + x_n(1-x_n) \le x_n^2+ x_n(1-x_n)= x_n$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thank you very much!

Comment: I realize that I still haven't solved the $x_n > 0$.Could you give some hints?@mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: By induction again as we're integrating non negative maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$0\le x_{n+1} = 1/2 x_n^2 +x_n(1-x_n) \le x_n$$

Hence the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is positive and non increasing. Therefore it converges.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** By induction, we readily find $0\le x_{n+1}\le x_n$.

**Bonus Hint.** In fact, $x_{n+1}= x_n-\frac12x_n^2$. Conclude that $x_n\to 0$.

Comment: Note that $1/x_{n+1}\gt(1/x_n)+(1/2)$

Comment: How to prove $0<x_n<1$.Can you give me a detailed process?I'm just a little confused here.